# Spring Integration : Scatter-Gather, Gather not working after parallel web service calls

Tags: spring-integration, scatter

I'm setting up spring integration flow to consume messages from MQ and make parallel calls to web-service calls by creating requests created from MQ Messages.

Below is how the spring integration flow look like

- Consume message from IBM MQ,transform the message using Marshaller and save entity to DB.
- Send Saved Entity to Scatter-Gather Channel.
- Scatter-Gather Channel has two distribution channels, each distribution channel is a chain with following components

  1. Webservice Client to make a webservice Call (Service Activator)
  2. Transformer to convert response to Entity Object
  3. Handler to save data to DB.
- Gather the response from parallel webservice calls and send the new object created from two parallel webservice calls to RabbitMQ.

I am able to make parallel webservice calls from scatter-gather pattern but i don't see aggregation happening in my gather pattern, basically flow is not coming to gatherer class.

I tried Publish-Subscribe channel with task-executor as input channel for Scatter-Gather Pattern and as per logs webservice calls are happening parallel with two task-executors but it never reaches to gatherer after webservice call.

```
<si:service-activator input-channel="transformedEntity"
        ref="incidentHandler" output-channel="outputChannelFromMQ" />

<si:scatter-gather input-channel="outputChannelFromMQ" 
        requires-reply="false" output-channel="gatherResponseOutputChannel" gather-channel="gatherChannel" gather-timeout="4000">
        <si:scatterer apply-sequence="true">
            <si:recipient channel="distributionChannel1" />
            <si:recipient channel="distributionChannel2" />
        </si:scatterer>         
</si:scatter-gather>

<si:publish-subscribe-channel id="outputChannelFromMQ" apply-sequence="true" 
        task-executor="taskExecutor" />

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" queue-capacity="25"    pool-size="10-10" />

<si:chain id="planngedBagsChain" input-channel="distributionChannel1"
        output-channel="gatherChannel">
    <si:service-activator ref="webServiceClient1" method="getResponse" />
    <si:service-activator ref="serviceHandler1"     method="saveToDB" />
</si:chain>

<si:chain id="bagHistoryChain" input-channel="distributionChannel2"
    output-channel="gatherChannel">
    <si:service-activator ref="webServiceClient2" method="getResponse" />
    <si:transformer ref="transformer" />
    <si:service-activator ref="serviceHandler2" method="saveToDB" />
</si:chain>

<si:service-activator input-channel="gatherResponseOutputChannel"
    ref="responseTransformer" method="receiveResponse" output-channel="toRabbitMQ" />
```

Comment: Does your `saveToDB` return anything? The result of that method(s) call is going to be sent to the `gatherChannel`.

Comment: yes, debugged the code both the webservice client returns objects after DB save is successful.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Both your `<si:chain>` have something like `<si:service-activator ref="serviceHandler1"     method="saveToDB" />` in the end. And according your configuration that `saveToDB` happens already after a service call. So, the question is: what is going on in that `saveToDB` method?

Comment: Well, you can simply enable `DEBUG` logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and you'll see in logs how your messages are traveling.

Comment: Also, if i remove requires-reply='false' attribute and try then i get `org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.scattergather.ScatterGatherHandler#0', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true', so basically reply is not produced by scattergatherhandler.

Comment: Well, that just may mean that `gatherer` part doens't receive any replies from your distribution. Therefore a question about `saveToDB`. If that method doesn't return anything, there is nothing going to be sent to the `gatherChannel` and, therefore, nothing will be produced from the scatter-gather at all.

Comment: Thanks@ArtemBilan. I figured out the issue. Actually enabling debug logs helped to identify the issue.Responses were going to gatherChannel but I have a serviceactivator with outputchannel as 'gatherResponseOutputChannel', after changing it to gatherChannel it worked.

Comment: Great! May you form it as an answer to let other people do not step on the same rake. It’s hard from here to make a useful resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling debug logs, able to find out all the channels it is being sent to. With above configuration it is not going to right gatherer. Changing to below configuration worked.

```
<si:service-activator input-channel="transformedEntity"
        ref="incidentHandler" output-channel="outputChannelFromMQ" />

<si:channel id="outputChannelFromMQ"></si:channel>

<si:scatter-gather input-channel="outputChannelFromMQ"
         requires-reply="false" scatter-channel="scatterInputChannel" output-channel="toRabbit"  
         gather-channel="gatherChannel" gather-timeout="4000">
        <si:gatherer id="responseGatherer"  ref="responseTransformer" release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"/>
    </si:scatter-gather>

<si:publish-subscribe-channel id="scatterInputChannel" apply-sequence="true" 
        task-executor="taskExecutor" />

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" queue-capacity="25"    pool-size="10-10" />

<si:chain id="planngedBagsChain" input-channel="scatterInputChannel"
        output-channel="gatherChannel">
    <si:service-activator ref="webServiceClient1" method="getResponse" />
    <si:service-activator ref="serviceHandler1"     method="saveToDB" />
</si:chain>

<si:chain id="bagHistoryChain" input-channel="scatterInputChannel"
    output-channel="gatherChannel">
    <si:service-activator ref="webServiceClient2" method="getResponse" />
    <si:transformer ref="transformer" />
    <si:service-activator ref="serviceHandler2" method="saveToDB" />
</si:chain>
```